# MySQL SUM function doesn't behave linear

Tags: mysql, math

The difference of two sums should be equal two the sum of the differences - mathematically speaking.

[image: difference of sums equals sum of differences]

Where `t` is the turnovers and `c` is the costs.

Translating this to MySQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(`turnovers`) - SUM(`costs`) as `profitA`, 
  SUM(`turnovers` - `costs`) as `profitB` 
FROM `mytable`
```

The two result fields "profitA" and "profitB" should be identical. I'm getting two different results, though. How is that possible?

Example table to replicate this behaviour:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `turnovers` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `costs` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`date`, `turnovers`, `costs`) VALUES
('2020-09-11', '697.60', '453.20'),
('2020-09-12', '480.90', '332.30'),
('2020-09-15', NULL, '444.90');
```

Comment: [Why should I provide an mcve for what seems to me to be a very simple sql query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
SUM(`turnovers`) - SUM(`costs`)
```

sums each column separately ignoring NULL values and subtracts the results

```
SUM(`turnovers` - `costs`)
```

sums only rows in which neither value is NULL

So if single fields are NULL, the sums differ.

Here's an mcve:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `turnovers` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `costs` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `mytable`
--

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`date`, `turnovers`, `costs`) VALUES
('2020-09-11', '697.60', '453.20'),
('2020-09-12', '480.90', '332.30'),
('2020-09-15', NULL, '444.90');
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(`turnovers`) - SUM(`costs`) as `profitA`, 
  SUM(`turnovers` - `costs`) as `profitB` 
FROM `mytable`
```